# Fragment shaders: output variables

Tags: opengl, glsl, shader

Reading the GLSL 1.40 specification:

> Fragment outputs can only be float,
>   floating-point vectors, signed or
>   unsigned integers or integer vectors,
>   or arrays of any these. Matrices and
>   structures cannot be output. Fragment
>   outputs are declared as in the
>   following examples:
>
> out vec4 FragmentColor;
>   out uint Luminosity;

The fragment color is defined writing gl_FragColor... is it right? Somebody could clear my ideas about these outputs? May I write only 'FragmentColor' of the example to determine fragment color? May I read back them ('Luminosity' for example)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your example has 2 outputs. They have corresponding FBO slots associated after GLSL program linking. You can redirect them using `glBindFragDataLocation`.

Once you activated the shader and bound FBO, it all depends on a draw mask, set by `glDrawBuffers`. For example, if you passed `GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0` and `GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT2` there, that would mean that output index 0 will go to the attachment 0, and output index 1 would go to the color attachment 2.

Answer (score 17):

The global output variable gl_FragColor is deprecated after GLSL version 120.
Now you have to give it a name and type by yourself, as in your example.
Regarding several outputs, 
this link gives you information about the mapping: http://www.opengl.org/wiki/GLSL_Objects#Program_linking

(And I found that link at: http://www.opengl.org/discussion_boards/ubbthreads.php?ubb=showflat&Number=270999 )

Hope this helps! :D

*Ooops! I see that kvark gave the relevant information. Anyway, maybe you got something out of my text too.*

Answer (score 0):

i want to give some examples:

```
void add(in float a, in float b, out float c)
{
    //you can not use c here. only set value
    //changing values of a and b does not change anything.
    c = a + b;
}

void getColor(out float r, out float g, out float b)
{
   //you can not use r, g, b here. only set value
   r = gl_FragColor.r;
   g = gl_FragColor.g;
   b = gl_FragColor.b;
}

void amplify(inout vec4 pixelColor, in value)
{
   //inout is like a reference
   pixelColor = pixelColor * value;
}
```